# Java Code working in eclipse, not working when packed into jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jdbc, jar

I have a spring batch processing project, which is running perfect in eclipse.
I generated the executable Jar file and set the referenced jar files in the classpath, 
When I run the executable jar file in command line, it throw Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sprigframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
```

my project needs to get jdbc connection first, and this exception means no connection created.

I packed the referenced jars into the executable jar, so I am sure the jar is there, but java could not load it.

I tried to use remote debug to debug this jar, it fails at the very beginning of load class.

Anyone has idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: extract the jar and make sure again that jar is there. How are you making it as executable Jar file?

Comment: You mean the jars are just embedded as jars in the executable jar?

Comment: The cause is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.  Missing a jar from your deployment?

Comment: I extracted the jar, and all referenced jars are there, the classpath is also well formed, it is just strange to encounter ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error is because

> Fatal exception thrown when we can't connect to an RDBMS using JDBC.

The JDBC .jar library you have in your project, but not in the correct directory in your final .jar file.

Or when you're running your jar file in command line, make sure the jdbc .jar file is in your CLASSPATH.